# c# progressbar not working correctly

Tags: c#, progress-bar

I have a progressbar in my application, what it is supposed to do is equal to the counter value. The max of the progress bar is 100 and the min is 0. When the program is ran it only increases the bar a very small percentage.

```
while (counter < numericUpDown1.Value)
{
     timer1.Start();
     client.Send(message);
     counter++;
     timer1.Stop();
     progressBar1.Value = counter;
}
```

Comment: 1. are you sure numericUpDown1 value isn't equal to the small percentage you're getting?
2. it may be that you're blocking the UI thread (but since there is no context it may be not) and this prevent the UI to refresh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have set your max to 100 so make sure that your counter reaches 100. put this and try it 
`progressBar1.Maximum = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use `Application.DoEvents();` each time you change its value.

Answer (score 0):

Fabio is correct, if numericdown1 is only 5, your progress bar will only increment to 5 so you would need to do something like (NumberDown1.Value / 100) * 100 to get what you should increment your Progress Bar (Prior to the while loop, not inside it). Then I would create a delegate to update the UI thread with your value if its winforms or if its WPF use the Dispatcher.